# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'in'

Tags: sql-server

For the below query, I'm getting this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'in'

Query:

```
SELECT shedule.shedulId, shedule.shedudate, shedule.hometeam, shedule.awayteam
FROM shedule
where in
(Select homeplay.shedulId from homeplay, shedule where shedule.shedulId != homeplay.shedulId);
```

Comment: you are missing the column name that needs to go with in keyword and so the error!

Answer (score 1):

Reading your comment to another response, I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT h.shedulId, 
       s.shedudate, 
       s.hometeam, 
       s.awayteam
FROM   homeplay h 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
       shedule s ON 
       h.shedulId = s.shedulId
WHERE  s.shedulId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something in front of the IN operator.

```
SELECT shedule.shedulId, shedule.shedudate, shedule.hometeam, shedule.awayteam
FROM shedule
where SOMETHING_IS_MISSING_HERE in (Select homeplay.shedulId
                                    from homeplay,shedule
                                    where shedule.shedulId!=homeplay.shedulId)
```

Or are you trying to use IN instead of EXISTS?

Comment: it s not working , i want select all homeplay.shID witch are not equal to the shedul.sheID

Answer (score 0):

Sample usage of IN

```
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName, e.JobTitle
FROM Person.Person p
JOIN HumanResources.Employee AS e
    ON p.BusinessEntityID = e.BusinessEntityID
WHERE e.JobTitle IN ('Design Engineer', 'Tool Designer', 'Marketing Assistant');
GO
```

For details see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Correct statement would be:

```
SELECT shedule.shedulId, shedule.shedudate, shedule.hometeam, shedule.awayteam
FROM shedule
WHERE shedule.shedulId IN
(SELECT homeplay.shedulId FROM homeplay, shedule WHERE shedule.shedulId != homeplay.shedulId);
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this,it will give result that you want

```
select s.shedulId, s.shedudate, s.hometeam, s.awayteam
from shedule s left join homeplay h on s.shedulId=h.shedulId
where h.shedulId is null
```

Comment: thanq soooo much .. :)